# Google spreadsheet function to match, copy, delete and paste into new sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to find and match cell `F2` with range `A2:A8`.

If `F2` is found in between the range `A2:A8` then copy the matching rows to `sheet2` and delete the entire row from `sheet1`. There should be no overlapping while pasting the data in `sheet2`.

Comment: You know, we usually expect to see anything you tried to achieve what you need. then it actually feels like helping rather than doing the work for you ;) It seems like you need to employ Google Apps Script. Can you show us your code?

Comment: I am not a programmer, I tried looking into https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet. but I was more puzzled. I can manipulate Excel vb scripts but not make one by myself but this is completely new for me so i needed some code to start with. As I told earlier I am not a programmer so I copy codes from internet and manipulate it. :(

Comment: Have you thought about the case if a match was found in A2? Then you would want to send the row from Sheet1 to Sheet2 together with the cell F2?

Comment: Yes you are right I will make a different sheet lets call it Sheet3.F2.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. It would be very helpful if you could let me know how to start the coding. There is no record and edit method in spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not a good developer in Google Apps Script, but I've created a function which I hope will help you.

In your spreadsheet you should go to <kbd>Tools</kbd> > <kbd>Script Editor...</kbd>. Insert this code:

```
function test() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheetOne = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var sheetTwo = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet2");
  var sheetThree = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet3");
  var data = sheetOne.getDataRange().getValues();
  var columnCount = data[0].length
  var firstCol = sheetOne.getRange("A2:A8");
  var matchValue = sheetThree.getRange("F2").getValue();
  var j = sheetTwo.getLastRow() + 1;

  for (var i = 0; i < firstCol.getValues().length; ++i) {
    if (firstCol.getValues()[i][0] === matchValue) {
      sheetOne.getRange(i+2,1,1,columnCount).copyTo(sheetTwo.getRange(j,1,1,columnCount));
      sheetOne.deleteRow(i+2);
      i = i - 1;
      j = j + 1;
    }
  }
}
```

Then select your function:

[image]

And click the Run button:

[image]

Maybe there's a better way to run the function, but I simply don't know it. :) Hope you'll be able to manipulate this code.

Comment: Hello again Zygd!  I tried running this script and it works good. But I am getting problem because everytime the script runs it pastes the data over previous one in sheet2. "it's overlapping the data".

Comment: sorry about that ZygD, and thanks for teaching me about the ✓ symbol

Comment: I have updated the answer. The row `var j = j + 1` was changed to `var j = sheetTwo.getLastRow() + 1;`

Comment: Thanks ZygD for your kindness. I have started training my self in code academy to learn about loop and all so that next time i would be able to write some code. Thanks again dear.